# Dynamic ngModel object attribute inside ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my code, I want to use dynamic object as ng-model:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key,value) in importdata.fields">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >
        {{value}}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select ng-model="form.{{key}}" ng-options='column as column for column in importdata.columns' class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>
{{form | json }}
```

I want to show result like this:

```
{
    name:'john',
    family:'Doe'
}
```

or

```
{
   name:'john',
   family:'' 
}
```

Comment: can you add importdata.fields in your question??

Comment: my fields is dynamic but like above example is `name`, `family`, etc

Comment: your information is litle. please explain more and put also more data.

Comment: it's related to import data mapping form, I want to import data from file and this section I want to map fields to xls file columns. Now I want to create object with attribute that is my table fields and pass one object to server backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access dynamic property by variable name:

```
ng-model="form[value]"
```

By the way, there is nothing Angular specific here, the same in normal JS.